# ¿Cómo evitar que el teclado oculte el EditText en modo horizontal en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

Por defecto cuando se presiona un EditText en modo Landscape se oculta la aplicacion y solo se despliega el teclado y se expande el EditText, me gustaria que solo se abra el teclado pero que el EditText no se expanda.

Ejemplo:
Quisiera que al igual que al ingresar texto verticalmente se vea horizontalmente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin que el EditText abarque la mitad superior de la pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: a qué te refieres con _EditText no se expanda_ ?

Answer (score 1):

No tengo tu código XML pero solo debes agregar la propiedad "**imeOptions**":

```
<EditText
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:id="@+id/et_nombre"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />
```

De este modo el EditText conservara su vista y solo se desplegará el teclado de android